# What is apache handlers equivalent in Lighttpd

Tags: apache2, configuration, lighttpd

Hi experts can somebody give some clues about this.

In httpd.conf we use user defined handlers like

**AddHandler ctc-handler getLauncher**

What is the **equivalent of userdefined apache handlers in Lighttpd**.

Answer (score 0):

It's `lighttpd.conf` and is stored in `/etc/lighttpd`. See this [Tutorial Configuration - Lighttpd](http://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/1/wiki/TutorialConfiguration).

Comment: yes that is a configuration file, but how to implement handler functionality in lighttpd.conf

Comment: Or what we call handlers(apache) in lighttpd

Comment: For this I gave that link. Or you want to search it for you? Anyways, you better ask this question on http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/. Its place is not here, on this site.